# Using svg to create map on website

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, svg

I am about to create a map where you can choose a seat (in a booking context). I want the map to show the seats and which are available and which are not. The user should be able to pick a seat just by clicking the map.

My idea is to have the map in a svg image file on the server and then change it (change color on a clicked seat for instance), when the user interacts with it. Is this a good way to solve this problem? I will handle the position click with javascript and just send the position to the python server, which will change the svg image, and then update it with ajax.

I would like to know if this is a good or bad solution, and also if there is an obvious better one out there.

Comment: This is not really an appropriate question for Stack Overflow as it is a recommendation request.  Having said that, your suggested approach is a reasonable one that many others have used.

Comment: Is it perhaps better to make use of the html5 canvas element? I realized that it is almost the same approach as using svg.

Comment: It's much harder to highlight the seat or implement hover effects if you use Canvas.

Comment: Hm, that is probably true... Which is best for performance issues? Loading an image every time seems like a bad idea, but svg might not be so heavy to load?

Comment: It's hard to say which would be smaller.  It would depend on image size and how efficiently you write the SVG.